# Variable Rewrite for multiple .php pages

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Im trying to access two of my pages and rewrite their urls with .htaccess.

First page I'm trying to access:

> http://api.aotikbot.tv/polls.php?username=aotik

Second page I'm trying to access:

> http://api.aotikbot.tv/getpoll.php?poll=917529

My current .htaccess code:

```
# Apache Rewrite Rules

 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

# Add trailing slash to url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/|#(.*))$
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]

# Remove .php-extension from url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
  RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z0-9-]+/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ polls.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
  RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z0-9-]+/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ getpoll.php?poll=$1 [NC,L]

  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.php 
  # Remove .html-extension from url
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
  RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ $1.html 

# End of Apache Rewrite Rules


 </IfModule>
```

The first page works as /polls/username but the second doesn't read the poll value and I think redirects to polls.php.

Could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: They're both the same rule, so you'll only ever get to `polls.php` because it's first. Don't you want the URLs to be something like `/polls/username` and `/getpoll/poll`?

Comment: Also it would kind of help if you posted what you want your URLs to look like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z0-9-]+/([0-9-]+)/?$ getpoll.php?poll=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^[A-Za-z0-9-]+/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ polls.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
```

Here, I've swapped your two rules around, so we check for IDs first (for `getpoll` - note how I have removed letters from the expression). If we're not doing an ID check (ie, there are letters in the segment), then it'll rewrite for `polls`.

**Update:**

Per arco444, if the username is a number, this wouldn't work. This is a more specific solution:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^getpoll/([0-9-]+)/?$ getpoll.php?poll=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^polls/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ polls.php?username=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Sure, this is based on the fact that it would never be the case... It'd be better to check for each file instead of checking for `^[A-Za-z0-9-]`.

Comment: It worked mate, thanks a lot really appreciate it! So this would work now if the username is/contains numbers right? (The updated version)

Comment: Correct, as we're specifying the page instead of assuming its format. Glad it worked for you. :-)

Comment: Cheers buddy, been killing myself trying to make it work since last night, again thank you ;)